# Devise: RoutingError prevents sign up of new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I type in a new email, password, and password confirmation in my Devise app. When I go to actually do the signup, I get the following error:

> *RoutingError*
>
> `No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"`
>
> Try running `rake routes` for more information on available routes.

It looks like `new_registration_path` takes you to `users/sign_up`, which it doesn't know about (at least when getting a POST). How do I make it recognize this?

Below are some relevant bits of code.

---

Here's the (possibly) relevant `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

Here's the output of `rake routes`:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
       static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)   static_pages#home
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
              businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)          businesses#index
                         POST   /businesses(.:format)          businesses#create
            new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)      businesses#new
         ed  it_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format) businesses#edit
                business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#show
                         PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
                         DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#destroy
                    root        /                              static_pages#home
```

Here's the form in registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => new_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `registration_path` instead of `new_registration_path` because sign up is performed via `POST` request to `/users`.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```